# I am creating html eblast and when I send a test message, all images and videos moves from its position

Tags: html, css

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Untitled Document</title>
 
</head>

<body style="position: fixed;">
 <div style="position: fixed; margin: auto; display: block;">
 <img src="https://image.ibb.co/mMxcMp/Untitled_1.png" alt="Untitled_1" border="0" width="750" style="position: relative; top: 0; left: 0; z-index: 1">
 <img src="https://image.ibb.co/c2LYSU/workeefy.png" alt="workeefy" border="0" width="50" style="position: absolute; top: 1018px; left: 180px; z-index: 2;">
  <a href=""><img src="https://image.ibb.co/kJfKZ9/apple_store.png" alt="apple_store" border="0" width="150" style="position: absolute; top: 1020px; left: 20px; z-index: 3;"></a>
  <a href=""><img src="https://image.ibb.co/jrF8SU/google_play_logo.png" alt="google_play_logo" border="0" width="150" style="position: absolute; top: 1020px; left: 241px; z-index: 4;"></a>
  <a href="">
   <img src="https://image.ibb.co/mWBwxU/workeefy.gif" alt="workeefy" border="0"style="position: absolute; top: 150px; left: 320px; z-index: 5;">
  </a>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

[this is what I get after sending test message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8O3sE.png) here is the code, plus I am attaching images before sending and after sending test message.

[this is what I want](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cSj1F.png)

Answer (score 0):

You need to use a table to format html in an email. Your inline styles are the right way to do it, but I think you'll need to use nested tables to get something you can depend on.

https://support.e2ma.net/Resource_Center/Account_how-to/basic-format-for-your-own-html-emails